# Pivot with multiple Header items and a single PivotItem

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Is it somehow possible to create a `Pivot` with a single `PivotItem` and multiple headers to create an effect like there are multiple `PivotItem`s but a single one is displayed.

All the pivot items will be the same type and will have a single template.

One of the problems is when my `Pivot` contains only one item then the pivot becomes unscrollable (unswipeable).

I need such behavior to reuse the created view and reduce memory consumption.

I have tried changing the pivot style but no luck yet. Maybe anyone has created something similar and can help me out.

Comment: I think you can have multiple `PivotItem`s, and put your content in the first item, and handle it's `SelectionChanged` event to remove your content from one `PivotItem` and add it to another. Does that fill your requirement?

Comment: Actually it is working. I am using Caliburn.Micro so I needed to create a few hacks but it works. The only thing you need to make sure is to always clear the Content of the items that are not visible. Put your comment in a seperate answer so I can mark it as the answer for my question . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple `PivotItem`s and one content. Initially your content would be in the first `PivotItem`. Then in `SelectionChanged` event, remove your content from previous `PivotItem` (set it's content `null`) and add it to current selected one.

Here's an example:

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="myPivot" Title="MYPIVOT" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="one" Header="one">
        <Grid x:Name="content">
            <!-- Place content here -->
        </Grid>
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="two" Header="two" />
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="three" Header="three" />
</phone:Pivot>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
    PivotItem selected;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selected = one;
    }

    private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selected.Content = null;

        switch(myPivot.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                one.Content = content;
                selected = one;
                break;
            case 1:
                two.Content = content;
                selected = two;
                break;
            case 2:
                three.Content = content;
                selected = three;
                break;
        }
    }
```